# how to publish a web application with all configuration of application?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp-classic, iis-6

i am working on an web application which is used to send data to devices which is connected in a network(LAN). software is able to send data when it is published through visual studio 2010 and  when i am publishing on IIS 6 this software is not able to send data on devices.

Answer (score 0):

(From MSDN)
To publish a Web application project

1. In the Build menu, click Publish ProjectName.
2. The Publish Web dialog box is displayed.
3. Click the ellipsis button (…) to browse to the location that you
   want to publish the Web application project to.
4. Select the Replace matching files with local copies check box or the Delete all existing files prior to publish check box.
5. Select how you want to copy the Web application project files to the new location by using Only files needed to run this application, All project files, or All files in the source project folder.
6. You can include files from the App_Data folder by selecting the corresponding check box.
7. Click OK to publish the Web application project.
8. In the task bar, Publish succeeded is displayed when publishing has finished.
9. Make any configuration changes that are required for the Web application at the target location.
   For more information, see How to: [Configure Published Web Site Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdt9aht6(v=vs.100).aspx).

Hope it helps